# Replace NA with Blank using Sql in R

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to replace NA with Blank using Sql in R. I used below code but I still get "NA" instead of blank!

DF_TEST_PN <- sqldf("Select *,
Case when Proj_Loess ='NA' then ' ' else Proj_Loess end as New_Proj_Loess
From Test")

Comment: I suspect `NA` is just how R is showing a missing value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ifnull`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) in `sqldf`/`sqLite`:

```
test <- tibble(Proj_Loess=c(NA,"test"))
DF_TEST_PN <- sqldf("Select *, ifnull(Proj_Loess,' ') as New_Proj_Loess From test")

  Proj_Loess New_Proj_Loess
1       <NA>               
2       test           test
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have DF as shown below.  The NAs in R are represented by null in SQL so use `coalesce` as shown below.  `coalesce` looks at each argument in turn and returns the first one that is not null, i.e. not NA.  `coalesce` is available in all backends that sqldf supports (sqlite, h2, mysql, postgresql).

```
library(sqldf)

DF <- data.frame(A = c("A", NA, "B", NA, "C"))
sqldf("select *, coalesce(A, '') as V1 from DF")
```

giving:

```
     A V1
1    A  A
2 <NA>   
3    B  B
4 <NA>   
5    C  C
```

If you want to use `case when` as in the question then use `is null` like this:

```
sqldf("select *, case when A is null then '' else A end as V1 from DF")
```